# how do we organize our site's (navigation) pages in Google search?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, http-headers, navigation

**Is there a HTML technique for organizing my site's main pages in Google (navigation)?
Or is it made by a Google's specific tool for creating a result layout like in this picture?**

[image]

**Look at the difference of the results for my site:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about are [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334). They're automated by Google so you can't really control them. You can, however, demote Sitelinks you don't link if they do start appearing.

Comment: Understood, sir!

Comment: Glad to help! Even though the question's been marked as a duplicate, you can still accept it by clicking the check mark on the left :)

Comment: 5 minutes to go...